# How to use SQL against a CSV file

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I would like to use a SQL query on a CSV file using C#. There is something like this for java [here](http://www.hxtt.com/). Is there anything like this for c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the appropriate OLE DB provider to query the text file. You can find the query string here:

[Textfile Connection String Samples](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile)

Comment: Is there any way to parse different Date format values using OLE DB with CSV file. Like `mm.dd.yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use ODBC to run a query against a CSV File :

```
// using System.Data.Odbc;

string strConn = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" +
    "Dbq=C:;Extensions=csv,txt";

OdbcConnection objCSV = new OdbcConnection(strConn);
objCSV.Open();

OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand("select column1,column2 " +
    "from THECSVFILE.CSV", objCSV);
OdbcDataReader oDR = oCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (oDR.Read())
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// need to add
// using System.Linq;

void Main()
{
    var path = @"C:\myfile.csv";
    string csv = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( path );
    var array = csv.Split(new[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // Do the mapping with your databinding object
    var personArray = array.Select(p => new Person { Name = p}); 
   // You need to have this DataContext defined somewhere, for instance using LinqToSql
    using(var context = new PersonDataContext()){ 
        context.InsertAllOnSubmit(personArray);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    } 
}

// Imagine this class is one of linqToSql class
public class Person{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: LINQ is another way get result although the OP asked explicitly sql query

Comment: this only works if your csv file is small enough to fit into memory

Answer (score 1):

So, do you mean using Linq?

Something like one of these?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/05/24/linq-to-csv-getting-data-the-way-you-want.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/30/linq-to-text-and-linq-to-csv.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Openrowsets .

Enable SQL Ad Hoc/Openrowset in SQL configuration first. Once enabled you'll be able to connect your SQL Server Managerment studio and query Excel and comma delimited files.

Your queries will look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DefaultDir={your path}','SELECT * FROM ypurtextfile.csv')
```

You can use these queries in your C# code just like you query any other tables.
Just check with your manager that he's ok with you enabling ad hoc on the SQL Server

Comment: this is great idea if you need to import from text or csv file frequently into the sql database.
for those just want to query and show the result, the first answer is probably better
I also prefer the first answer when the database under DB Admin control.