# How to use csv files hierarchicaly as database?

Tags: c#, database, text

I use csv files as database in seperate processes. I only store all data or read all data in my datagrid in singular relationship. Every field in every txt file is one and only number starting from zero.

```
//While reaching countries, i read allcountries.txt, 
//while reaching cities, i read allcities.txt       
//while reaching places i read allplaces.txt.
```

but one country has many cities and one city has many places. Yet, i don't use any relationship. I want to use and i know there is some needs for this. How can i reach data for reading and writing by adding all text files one extra column?

And is it possible to reach data without sql queries?

Comment: You mean "one city has many places", not "one city has many countries" right?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use csv files and not SQL?

Comment: Yes, this txt files will be in an sd card and should be portable for editing by a microprocessor. Ad practically readable on any platform without any program(or less requirements).

Comment: Hi I4V, i am not able to. Any text file would be better.

Comment: XML is a good choice for documents that are human and machine readable at the same time. Also, did you mean "portable for editing by a word processor" instead of "portable for editing by a microprocessor"?

Comment: Just microprocessor, in an electronical circuit.

Comment: Remember to mark one of these questions as the answer if it ends up being useful to you, or to update us as to why the solutions don't work so we can find one that does.

Comment: Since i have not enough reputation, i can't rate answers:) but yes, i had chosen one as accepted.

Comment: also thank you for your response msm8bball...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text files don't have any mechanism for `SELECT`s or `JOIN`s.  You'll be at a pretty steep disadvantage.

However, LINQ gives you the ability to search through object collections in SQL-like ways, and you can certainly create entities that have relationships.  The application (whatever you're building) will have to load everything from the text files at application start.  Since your code will be doing the searching, it has to have the entities loaded (from text files) and in-memory.

That may or may not be a pleasant or effective experience, but if you're set on replacing SQL with text files, it's not impossible.

Comment: With this method, the process becomes something like 1. Read all data from CSV. 2. Perform Manipulations using LINQ 3. Write the entire file back as a CSV.

Comment: I guess I was sort of hoping that we could read in all the text files and not write them again.  If they will be frequently written to, this plan goes from "pretty unpleasant" to "horrific nightmare".

Comment: There's a need to add one extra column for the operation i wanted. Is there no way to query in c# methods?

Comment: Did you google "query in c# methods"?  Because you will learn about LINQ when you do that.

Comment: LINQ stands for Language Integrated Query. It's definitely possible to query and manipulate the CSV file with C# as dnord said. But there are much better formats for accomplishing what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are good for mass input and mass output. They are not good for point manipulations or maintaining relationships. Consider using a database. SQLite might be something useful in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it would make more sense to use XML instead of CSV. This meets your requirements for being human and machine readable, and XML has nice built in libraries for searching, manipulating, serializing etc.

Comment: It seems to worth searching. Is there initial libraries in c#?

Comment: Look in the System.XML and System.XML.Linq namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL queries in CSV files: [How to use SQL against a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624286/how-to-use-sql-against-a-csv-file), I have done it for reading but never for writing so I don't know if this will work for you.