# Fastest method to get data in struct array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I wrote a C# program that manages different text files and retrieves data, compare fields etc etc.

My procedure is to store the data from txt file into array of structs with different field (e.g. file name, file length, lines contained etc etc). For example a file can be

```
    Name1    ID1    Lenght1    Path1    User1
    Name2    ID1    Lenght2    Path1    User4
    Name3    ID2    Lenght2    Path3    User1
    ...
```

I put these fields in an array of structs

```
           NAME     ID     LENGHT     PATH     USER

    [0]    Name1    Id1    Lenght1    Path1    User1
    [1]    Name2    Id1    Lenght2    Path1    User4
    [2]    Name3    Id2    Lenght2    Path3    User1
    ...
```

And than I have to retrieve entire rows with specific corner, for example I want all lines with NAME=Name2 AND PATH=Path1. In the previous example I retrieve struct indexed with [1].

I need to get this kind of data as fast as possible when the data to analyze grow up.

Actually the idea is to have a for loop that cycles and compares all the fields in the struct and save the lines that respect the corner (e.g. NAME=Name2 AND PATH=Path1). Unfortunately this approach is so long, not acceptable. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For one thing using a struct for a data structure that large is going to cause a slowdown, why are you using a struct instead of a class?

Comment: _"idea is to have a

for

that cicles"_ ??

Comment: Provided the text files are in a delimited format like tab or comma separated, it's possible to query them as an Odbc data source. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624286/how-to-use-sql-against-a-csv-file for example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of a custom type, you could use LINQ to filter your array:

```
var items = yourArray
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Name2" && x.Path == "Path2");
```

Assuming `yourArray` was something like:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could read from your text file and into your type.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work. Another question, how can I use the variable items to have the rest of data? BR

Comment: @user2819934 I'm not sure what you're asking?