# Sorting and storing data

Tags: c#, storage

So I'm having real trouble trying to store data how I want it to be stored so I can display it later, basically I am loading a .CSV file into my program which has 3 columns, lets say animal gender and age. There are a total of 8 unique animals, 80 genders and 400 ages. So 1 animal may have 10 genders and 200 ages and so fourth, similar to a database, tables and columns.

I'm wanting to store these in a custom class of their own so I can pull say all genders of animal[1] and those 10 values would return. Sample CSV:

```
cat,blue,a
dog,male,p
dog,male,f
dog,female,l
```

The problem I'm having is with storing these values, as you can see they are not unique per line and looking at line 2 you can see the collection of dog under male should have p and f. I have tried separating them all into lists with dictionaries so I could map them to the correct places but always run into unique key problems.

The object I'm trying to store this data in is:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> Results = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
```

I have no 'method' to post to ask for assistance as I can't even get that far, I'm here to ask how I should go about getting this data stored. Rather than the above solution I have also tried a List of a custom class with 3 dictionaries to store and map the data but again failed.

Can anyone provide assistance on how I would sort, store and then access this data in a database like style of databases, tables and columns? Thank you! Or any nuget packages which could help maybe?

Comment: Is 'blue' a gender ?

Comment: Something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624286/how-to-use-sql-against-a-csv-file). You can query the file instead of trying to load it all into a custom class.

Comment: The problem of "store a complex data structure as a string" has been solved many times, most recently with JSON. I suggest [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Just serialize your dictionary as a JSON string and stick it in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class animal, for example:

```
class Animal
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Load your data into a `List<Animal> animals` and then you can query using linq. Example:

Query all dogs: `animals.Where(x => x.Name == "dog");`

Query all genders of dogs:

```
animals.Where(x => x.Name == "dog")
       .Select(x => x.Gender)
       .Distinct();
```